# Show a list to select word document then a macro will merge the info from excel to word

Tags: excel, vba

This is my macro to merge with word. 
I realize I need to do something more, where I get a prompt for a selection of sheets from a series of available word documents to merge (xx1,xx2...xx7). There are 6 word documents and 2 of those 6 I need another common word document to open (xx7). ie. When I select word document xx3 or xx6, I need 2 word documents to open. if I select xx3 word document then it opens xx3 and xx7 and if I select xx6 word document then it opens xx6 and xx7. In the meantime xx1, xx2, xx4, xx5, will open one word document. 
I would hate to repeat this macro 7 times each with the other word document name. Any chance I can get this covered in one macro? THANK YOU

```
Sub RunMergeAttachBOccupantProtection()

   Const wdFormLetters = 0
   wdOpenFormatAuto = 0
   Const wdSendToNewDocument = 0
   wdDefaultFirstRecord = 1
   wdDefaultLastRecord = -16

    Dim wd As Object
    Dim wdocSource As Object

    Dim strWorkbookName As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If wd Is Nothing Then
        Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set wdocSource = wd.Documents.Open("R:\Grants\AttachmentBOccupantProtection.docx")

    strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

    wdocSource.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters

    wdocSource.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
            Name:=strWorkbookName, _
            AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
            Revert:=False, _
            Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
            Connection:="Data Source=" & strWorkbookName & ";Mode=Read", _
            sqlstatement:="SELECT * FROM [" & ActiveSheet.Name & "$]"
    With wdocSource.MailMerge
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .SuppressBlankLines = True
        With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
            .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
        End With
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With

    wd.Visible = True
    wdocSource.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Set wdocSource = Nothing
    Set wd = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your procedure to accept the name of the document to be opened, then call it once for each doc that needs to be opened. Similar to this:

```
Sub RunMergeAttachBOccupantProtection(DocName as String)
  .
  .
  .
  Set wdocSource = wd.Documents.open("R:\Grants\" & DocName & ".docx")
  .
  .
  .
End Sub
```

Then you can run a quick test with this:

```
Sub TestDriver()

  Dim MyDoc as String

  MyDoc = "XX1"

  if MyDoc = "xx3" or MyDoc = "xx6" then
    RunMergeAttachBOccupantProtection("xx3")
    RunMergeAttachBOccupantProtection(MyDoc)
  Else
    RunMergeAttachBOccupantProtection(MyDoc)
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: But how do I get a list of documents I can select from then the macro opens that particular choice and if it's xx3 or xx6 it opens xx3 and xx7 or xx6 and xx7?